# Model a Course table with one Instructor and multiple Tutors

Tags: database, database-design

That is basically the question. 
What strategy would you follow to model a table `Course` given that it can only have one `Instructor` and multiple `Tutors`?

The key aspect here is that `Instructor` and `Tutor` have almost the same properties, except for one or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design like this:

1. `Course` table has fields like course_id, name, duration etc. with `course_id` as the primary key.
2. `Instructor` table has fields like instructor_id, name, contact, course_id with `course_id` is the foreign key.
3. `Tutor` table has fields like tutor_id, name, contact etc.
4. `Tutor_Extension` table has fields like sno, tutor_id, course_id with `tutor_id and course_id` as foreign keys.

This way your table is normalized and easy to query.

Note: Tutor_Extension columns can be duplicated itself in Tutor table, but since it also replicates other string data as well in Tutor table, it is better to pull out only id's of Tutor table into Tutor_Extension table.

[image]